# Getting a bash script to delete each input file it runs through

Tags: bash, shell-script

Given to me from my previously asked question, I am using a script that runs MP4Box using all .h264 files from /mnt/usb/Convert/ as input and placing each .mp4 output file into /mnt/usb/Converted/. Here is that script:

```
for f in /mnt/usb/Convert/*.h264; do
  n=${f/Convert/Converted}
  MP4Box -add "$f" "${n%.*}.mp4"
done
```

This script runs perfectly, except I overlooked the fact that I also need it to be able to delete each .h264 file it runs through, otherwise when I crontab the script, it keeps repeating the same files; obviously.

Does anybody have any simple suggestions for appending a way to delete each of the .h264 files after the script has run through them? I tried different forms of pipes, and "&&" but im having no luck.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The command to delete the file would just be `rm "$f"`.  If you want to check that the conversion happened successfully first you could do something like:

```
for f in /mnt/usb/Convert/*.h264; do
    n=${f/Convert/Converted}
    if MP4Box -add "$f" "${n%.*}.mp4"; then
        rm "$f"
    else
        printf '%s\n' "Failed to convert $f" >&2
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realize my mistake was so small... Much appreciated!